# Publishing windows service on Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, deployment, ftp, windows-services, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to publish my windows service application from my computer (developer computer) TO the development server.

So, I've created a ftp server in my server and what I want to achieve is:
The ability to export my application (in Release mode) to the server via FTP.

I've tried to use the "Publish" option (right click on my WindowsService project->Publish). But, this command publishes my project with ClickOnce file.

What I want is that the "publishing task" will basically copy all the "bin\realse*" files to the server directory. I'll start the service manually.

I'm using Visual studio 2013 (C#).

Do you know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't publish a Windows Service over ftp. You need to [build a proper installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html), or use something like [Remote Powershell](http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2012/3/22/install-a-windows-service-remotely-with-powershell.html).

Comment: Your "build a proper installer" link goes to an unrelated article.